# Vuefire and async fetch() in NuxtJS: Fails on page refresh

Tags: nuxt.js, vuefire

I am trying to use [Vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuefire.html#bind) in Nuxt's fetch method. It works on **initial** page load, however, if you refresh the browser, it will fail with the following console error:

[image: console error]

Here is the relevant code:

```
  async fetch() {
    await this.$bind(
      'comments',
      this.$fireStore
        .collection('comments')
        .where('photoId', '==', this.photo.id),
      {
        wait: true
      }
    )
  },
data() {
    return {
      comments: []
    }
  },
```

Anyone have any tips on how I can fix this so it also works if you refresh the browser? I am probably not writing the above code correctly. Thank you!

Comment: What is `this.$bind` doing here?  `async fetch()` will run server side or client side depending on the curcumstance, my guess is that this code does not work server side.

Comment: what if you move ` async fetch` to mounted?

Comment: then I will lose the whole point of Server side rendering for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare this.comments on fetch()

Now the firestore API in nuxt firestore module changed to this.$fire.firestore
https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/community/migrate

Answering Sergio: this.$bind came from Vuefire

https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuefire.html#bind

```
async fetch() {
    this.comments = await this.$bind(
      'comments',
      this.$fire.firestore
        .collection('comments')
        .where('photoId', '==', this.photo.id),
      {
        wait: true
      }
    )
  },
data() {
    return {
      comments: []
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do with `this.$bind`, but I guess you can make that work this way:

```
data() {
  return {
    comments: []
  }
},

async fetch() {
  this.comments = await this.$fireStore
    .collection('comments')
    .where('photoId', '==', this.photo.id),
  {
    wait: true
  }
},

fetchOnServer: false
```

You can check an example in the [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/#options).

Comment: Thanks. However, I need to render the comments on server side for SEO. Thus, I don't think setting `false` willwork for me.